# How does array.push & array.join(' ') act differently with css modules?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

A tutorial I'm following is using this method to change the color of a button dynamically:

```
    let buttonColor = [classes.Button]
    if (this.state.bool) {
        buttonColor.push(classes.Red)
    }

    return (
        <button 
            onClick={this.boolToggler} 
            alt={this.state.bool}
            className={buttonColor.join(' ')}>Toggle List
        </button>
    )
```

Here's the css file:

```
.Button {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font: inherit;
    padding: 10.5px 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Button:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: black;
}

.Button.Red {
    background-color: red;
}

.Button.Red:hover {
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

Wouldn't `buttonColor.join(' ')` just leave me with `classes.Button classes.Red`? how does it know to use classes.Button.Red?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `classes` object is, but inferring from your CSS that you want to simply add class names of `.Button` and `.Red` to your `button`, try this:

```
    let buttonColor = [".Button"]
    if (this.state.bool) {
        buttonColor.push(".Red")
    }

    return (
        <button 
            onClick={this.boolToggler} 
            alt={this.state.bool}
            className={buttonColor.join(' ')}>Toggle List
        </button>
    )
```